# parallel asynchronous jQuery-AJAX-Requests blocking each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I use jQuery to do some asynchronous background data fetching. I stumbled upon the problem, that more than one parallel request to the same URL does not finish, until the first request handler is finished.

I created a simple example to demonstrate the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="js">Click me!</button>
<div>Request 1: <span id="resp1">-</span></div>
<div>Request 2: <span id="resp2">-</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#js').click(function() {
        $('#resp1, #resp2').html('...');
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://stackoverflow.com',
            async : true,
            complete: function(request, textStatus) {
                $('#resp1').html('complete');
                alert('The second request is not completed, until you close this alert!'); 
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://stackoverflow.com',               
            async : true,
            complete: function(request, textStatus) { 
                    $('#resp2').html('complete');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After the button is clicked, two parallel AJAX-Requests are made. The first one is completed normally, but the second not until the alert of the first one is closed. The problem remains the same, if you move the second ajax Request into the complete-Event handler of the first one.

Is this a bug or a feature?
Is there a workaround?

**Edit:**

OK, I understand that alert() causes the problem. However I can't explain two other things.

1. When I move the second ajax-call into the complete handler of the first (before the alert()) and change the first ajax-call to be async:false, then it works. Shouldn't the alert() be causing the same problem??
2. The alert must be blocking more than the Browsers JS-Thread, because if I open the AJAX-Request in another tab, it still fails to load until I close the alert-Box in the first tab. JS not involved here. Strange. Is this perhaps another problem?

Comment: Simply don't use `alert()` - that's what is blocking, not the request.

Comment: `alert` completely halts the browser's JS thread. That's the issue. Always use `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your fast feedback! 
I assume the same goes for confirm(). I don't use this entirely for debugging purposes, but also to show messages to users. Is this bad practice? What are (simple) alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole premise of completing or not is purely based on a race condition between execution of the async requests because the `alert()` in the callback of the first async request.  If the second request was faster than the first (fast enough to make up for the fact that it was initiated after the first) then you wouldn't see what you are concerned about

about #1 no, this wouldn't be the same because when you have the ajax call before alert and when you use `async : false` the ajax request will finish completely before moving on (to the alert).  In other words, you are completely synchronous at that point because you are in the callback of the only asynchronous event.  Don't use `async: false` by the way.

as was said, `alert()` is blocking the execution.

FYI, you can make fiddles with this and play with timing -- Note the use of the `delay` in the `data` object of the request.  Note in this example how both finish because of the timing I set up, but if you reverse it then it won't finish until `alert()` is cleared.

In the end DO NOT USE `alert()`!!

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/6dLeB/)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. `alert()` blocks execution until it is closed.

What is happening when these lines are executed

```
$('#resp1').html('complete');
alert('The second request is not completed, until you close this
```

is that the first line fires the ajax request but the execution of the next line follows so quickly that the ajax request does not have time to finish. As soon as the modal alert dialogue is initialised, execution is suspended. The ajax request maybe in the state of still retrieving the response, maybe it is processing it but it will be paused until the alert is closed.

Comment: I understand. I edited my initial question, because I'm unsure if that is the only underlying problem...